# Keras model classifies images as the same class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras' pre-trained VGGNet16 as my base model, but I need to add layers on the end to make it work for my data. I've got the data pre-processed and formatted, so I'll jump to the part of the code actually involving the CNN.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow.keras as K
.
.
.
input_t = K.Input(shape=(224,224,3))

base_model = K.applications.VGG16(include_top=False,weights="imagenet",input_tensor=input_t)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model = K.models.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))

#Training
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-5),
                metrics = ['accuracy'])

#Fit
model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs = 3,
          validation_split = 0.1,
          validation_data =(x_test,y_test))

model.summary()
```

This code yields the following output.

```
Epoch 1/3
14/14 [==============================] - 48s 3s/step - loss: 0.5887 - accuracy: 0.2287 - val_loss: 0.4951 - val_accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 2/3
14/14 [==============================] - 48s 3s/step - loss: 0.5170 - accuracy: 0.2220 - val_loss: 0.4972 - val_accuracy: 0.2800
Epoch 3/3
14/14 [==============================] - 48s 3s/step - loss: 0.4982 - accuracy: 0.2265 - val_loss: 0.4975 - val_accuracy: 0.2200
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 125445    
=================================================================
Total params: 14,840,133
Trainable params: 125,445
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
Test loss: 0.4997282326221466
Test accuracy: 0.2720000147819519
```

All of my test images are being classified into the same class. Is there any reason for this?

Edit: Modified question upon realizing the model is running properly

Comment: It's already training on the modified model not on the base model.

Comment: @talos1904 Ah, so I edited my question so that it asks another problem I have given that the issue isn't with the model itself. I am getting all my images classified under the same class and it doesn't seem to change even when I add relu layers or change the learning rate.

Comment: Well that's a different question..that could happen due to many reasons. First, you need to realize that you're training only softmax layer. Maybe add one more layer before that and make it trainable. Also add relu after that. That should help in some improvement.

Comment: You have to train the model until the training loss reaches close to zero, that is not happening yet, train it for much more epochs.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I trained for 50 epochs and the loss was still around 0.49

Comment: Use the SGD optimizer, Adam is well known to fail when training VGG.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't a great solution, but I fixed this by making the last six layers trainable with the others trainable

```py
for layer in base_model.layers[:-6]:
    layer.trainable = False
```